# Cookies are generated and present in response header but not available or visible in the browsers application->storage

Tags: javascript, cookies, server, backend, mern

I don't know much about all this, but cookies are generated and authentication token is sent as part of response header. And it works on Thunder Client VSCode. But when run on website(client on 3000 and server on 5000) browser doesn't generate cookie. Please do say if i need to provide any code i used.
[This is the response header for the login endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONfds.png) and [This is for the authorization.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFONp.png) No cookies are set in this header. Cookies are set during login like this,

```
        res.cookie("authToken",authToken,{
            // path : '/',
            httpOnly : true,
            // sameSite : 'none',
            secure : true,
            maxAge : 1000*60*60*12
        })
        .json({success:true});
```

I think its because they're both running on different addresses. Should I try looking into proxy? I tried many small fixes, as i said i still don't know much about backend server stuff ill read up on it but is there any easy or small fix? Thanks is advance

Comment: Provide the relevant cookie code, otherwise it will be difficult or impossible for others to help you.

Comment: I added some screenshots. Can you please take a look at this and tell me if you need any more data. Thanks